# optical PS/2 mouse freezing, unfreezing

Tags: mouse

No USB adapter, straight PS/2 mouse occasionally freezing: the pointer is, while both buttons are working. Goes back to normal when unplugged/plugged back in.
I have read somewhere that legacy USB support has to be disabled in BIOS, which I've done with no affect on mouse behavior: it is a PS/2 mouse after all.
Such a behavior never has been noted in Windows and in freshly installed Mint XFCE.